# Excel Macro – Change the row based on value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I want to change the macro below to make it changes the color of part of the row, not the cell, based on the cell value.

If the value in cell E2 is "proof", then cells A2-E2 become red.

```
Sub ChangeColor()
lRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("E2:E" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
If cell.Value = "Proof" Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What does it currently do and do wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't a conditional formatting rule be more appropriate for on-the-fly row highlighting?

Answer (score 2):

It's a relatively simple change. Change `cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3` to a specific range as seen in the procedure below.

```
Sub ChangeColor()
lRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("E2:E" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
If cell.Value = "Proof" Then range("a" & cell.row & ":e" & cell.row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of rows to process, you may wish to abandon the loop process and work with a filter instead.

For A:E highlighting:

```
Sub highlight_Proof()
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            If .AutoFilter Then .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=proof"
            With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 5)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then _
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End With
        .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

For full row highlighting:

```
Sub highlight_Proof2()
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            If .AutoFilter Then .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=proof"
            With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then _
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End With
        .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I haven't wildcarded the search for *proof* but that is a small modification. It seems that your original code was looking for the entire cell value.

Answer (score 0):

With Conditional Formatting, select ColumnsA:E, HOME > Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$E1="proof"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red, OK, OK.